# LESS javascript evaluation errors with LESSPHP

Tags: javascript, less, evaluation, lessphp

I am getting errors when I try to use javascript evaluations.  I am using lessphp v0.3.8 to compile my LESS.

Even with an example eval provided by lesscss.org:

`` @var: `"hello".toUpperCase() + '!' `; ``

I get an error message:

> less compile error: parse error: failed at `@var: `"hello".toUpperCase() + '!'`; ` less/style.less on line 17 ­

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered the question on the issue on GitHub you made: https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/296

> lessphp is written in PHP, I don't have access to a JavaScript interpreter. There is nothing I can do other than let you run PHP code.

Comment: What about the v8js plugin for php? [PECL v8js](http://pecl.php.net/package/v8js)